# Change spotlight's calculator to degrees?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, spotlight

I use spotlight to perform calculations constantly, but at the moment the type of project I'm working on measures all angles in degrees.

Is there a way I can make spotlight's trigonometric functions default to degrees instead of radians?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add a **d** to the trigonometric function and it should work.

Example: *sin(x)* > *sin**d**(x)*. *sin(1)*=0.8414... *sin**d**(1)*=0.0174...

Comment: Thank you, perfect; I was completely unaware that this existed.