# Changing macOS Calculator to degrees mode?

Tags: mac, macos

Right now I am currently working on a few things that have to do with trigonometry. More specifically, Sine and Cosine. I am trying to use my computer's calculator to do so. The problem is, the answers always come up wrong. I read online that this is the result of your calculator not being in degrees mode. I have little idea of how to do this. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Picture of calculator]

Notes:

I am aware of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/249965/248407) already answered question. But, what is the D function? Does that even work anymore?

Comment: I've cropped the original image you posted and in the future please do not post an image of the entire Desktop, only post what's necessary to convey the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rad button in the lower left corner stands for Radians. That switches mode from degree to radians. In radian mode, the letters rad show up on the output screen.